# minipage: horizontally alingned figures with common caption

Tags: graphics, captions, minipage

I am using `minipage` to insert 3 figures horizontally, each having its sub-caption, and then a common caption.

My intention is to produce a figure like:

[image]

Reproducible ME:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig1}
  \caption{First}\label{fig:A}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig2}
  \caption{Second}\label{fig:B}
\endminipage\hfill
\minipage{0.32\textwidth}%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig3}
  \caption{Third}\label{fig:C}
\endminipage
\caption{Common caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Read the documentation of the subcaption package. It can do what you want.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you load the [subcaption](https://ctan.org/pkg/subcaption) package, as it provides an environment called `subfigure` (as well as one called `subtable`). A `subfigure` environment *is* a `minipage` environment that's been trained to know what to do when it encounters a `\caption` directive. Its default output settings correpond exactly to what you say you want to do.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx} 
\usepackage{subcaption}
\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!htb]
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig1}
  \caption{First}\label{fig:A}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig2}
  \caption{Second}\label{fig:B}
\end{subfigure}\hfill
\begin{subfigure}{0.32\textwidth}%
  \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{fig3}
  \caption{Third}\label{fig:C}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Common caption.}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```